# what is causing the list index out of range error here?

Tags: python, matrix

for the program to modify a given 10x10 matrix such that if a matrix cell mat[i][j] is 1 then make all the cells of ith row and jth column as 1

this is the code i wrote:

```
mat = []
for ele in range(10):
    row = list(map(int, input().split()))
    mat.append(row)

stor = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if mat[i][j]==1:
            while mat[i][j] in stor:
                j += 1
                if j==10:  
                    j=0
                    i+=1
                    if i==10:  
                        break
            if i<10 and j<10: 
                for k in range(10):
                    mat[k][j] = 1
                    mat[i][k] = 1
                    stor.append(mat[i][j])
                    stor.append(mat[k][j])
                    stor.append(mat[i][k])
            
for i in range(10):
    print(*mat[i])
```

the while loop here stores the already modified elements of the matrix to a list, so that it is not checked again. i am getting a list index out of range error. what needs to be corrected? or is there any other major mistake?

sorry for not putting this up eralier, but here is the sample input, and the required output, where the testcase fails:
input:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

expected output:

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

the error:

```
line 9, in <module>
    if mat[i][j]==1:
       ~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What happens if `input().split()` results in less than 10 items?

Comment: In the same vein, are you sure you have a 10x10 matrix? Does `print(mat)` look like what you expect before you get into that second set of `for` loops?

Comment: You've given us code that depends on sample input, which you did not show us...

Comment: the test cases are such that exactly 10 items are given, that is there always will be 10 rows, and 10 columns

Comment: Can you add to the question an example of a test case that fails?

Comment: You should share the error log for us to understand which lines are breaking and you should share the input as well.

Beyond that, your loop will never get i==10 and j==10 because range(10) will loop from 0 to 9.

Comment: Also, you're making us guess where the error is.  Please post the full error traceback message.

Comment: @slothrop But then it checks `if i < 10 and j < 10:`, so the code after that will not run if it's out of range. The next iteration won't go beyond, because `range()` doesn't care if you reassign `i`.

Comment: Don't save the values in the matrix in `stor`. You should save the row and column indexes.

Comment: sorry, ive now updated it with the sample input and expected output

Comment: @Barmar I think it does go out of range actually. `i` can get set to 10 on some iteration of the `j`-loop that isn't the last one. So at the start of the next iteration of the `j`-loop the code tries to access `mat[10][j]`. `range` doesn't care about reassignments, sure, but `i` doesn't get reset on every iteration of the `j` loop.

Comment: there is another approach that has given me the output, but i wanted to see if it works out this way too

Comment: You're incrementing `i` and `j` inside the loop, so they can exceed the limit of 10.  Don't do that?

Comment: @JohnGordon okayy i see why it is getting out of range now. how else can i rewrite the code for the same approach without that happening?

Comment: The short of it is, don't monkey with the variables with which you are iterating inside of the iterations. It's a code smell and makes it difficult to debug. As Barmar suggested, capture the points where you find a `1` inside the loop, then set the values afterwards.

Comment: @JNevill and Barmar, thanks, using the indexes is how i did get the output, with the following code ive now given as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same pattern as your code, you can loop through the matrix and identify the positions of `1` and make note of their `i,j` pair.

Once the positions are identified, only then go through and set the entire row/column to 1.

This not only makes your code easier to read, but also easier to debug:

Consider:

```
#loop through mat, if mat[row][col] == 1 grab the point to a new list
loci = [[row,col] for row in range(10) for col in range(10) if mat[row][col]==1]

for locus in loci:
    for i in range(10):
        mat[i][locus[1]] = 1
        mat[locus[0]][i] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mat=[]
for ele in range(10):
    row=list(map(int, input().split()))
    mat.append(row)
rows=[]
cols=[]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if mat[i][j]==1:
            rows.append(i)
            cols.append(j)
for row in rows:
    for j in range(10):
        mat[row][j]=1
for col in cols:
    for i in range(10):
        mat[i][col]=1
for i in range(10):
    print(*mat[i])
```

i did get the output by saving the indexes of the matrix elements where 1 occurred